# SWT DropTargetListener has empty event data under Mac OS X

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, swt, drag-and-drop

I'm currently experiencing a weird platform inconsistency between Mac OS X and Windows/Linux.

I've implemented an SWT `DropTargetListener` and tried to analyze the data dropped in the `dragEnter` method. Unfortunately, the `data` attribute of the `TransferData` contained in the `DropTargetEvent` parameter is always `null` on OS X (but becomes valid in `DropTargetListener.drop` method where it's too late to give user feedback).

It works fine under Windows and Linux.

Can anybody help me out? Or is this a *known* limitation of SWT DND under OS X?

Comment: My [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507559/drag-drop-not-working-on-mac) got me thinking that I might just need to upgrade to a newer version of SWT for Mac, but I've noticed that it performs worse in graphical operations and am therefore reluctant to do so. Were you ever able to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Since the [following bugzilla request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?query_format=advanced&short_desc_type=allwordssubstr&short_desc=&classification=Eclipse&product=Platform&component=SWT&long_desc_type=allwordssubstr&long_desc=TransferData&bug_file_loc_type=allwordssubstr&bug_file_loc=&status_whiteboard_type=allwordssubstr&status_whiteboard=&keywords_type=allwords&keywords=&op_sys=Mac+OS+X&op_sys=Mac+OS+X+-+Cocoa&emailtype1=substring&email1=&emailtype2=substring&email2=&bugidtype=include&bug_id=&votes=&chfieldfrom=&chfieldto=Now&chfieldvalue=&cmdtype=doit&order=Reuse+same+sort+as+last+time&field0-0-0=noop&type0-0-0=noop&value0-0-0=) only returns one old bug, I am not sure it is an active bug when it comes to "TransferData".

There is however a lot [more bugs declared for DnD on Mac](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?query_format=advanced&short_desc_type=allwordssubstr&short_desc=&classification=Eclipse&product=Platform&component=SWT&long_desc_type=allwordssubstr&long_desc=Drag&bug_file_loc_type=allwordssubstr&bug_file_loc=&status_whiteboard_type=allwordssubstr&status_whiteboard=&keywords_type=allwords&keywords=&op_sys=Mac+OS+X&op_sys=Mac+OS+X+-+Cocoa&emailtype1=substring&email1=&emailtype2=substring&email2=&bugidtype=include&bug_id=&votes=&chfieldfrom=&chfieldto=Now&chfieldvalue=&cmdtype=doit&order=Reuse+same+sort+as+last+time&field0-0-0=noop&type0-0-0=noop&value0-0-0=) like [this one](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=267381) which comes close to what you are describing.

Could you add the exact version of eclipse and its SWT plugin you are using ?