# Drag & drop not working on Mac

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, swt

I'm trying to make it possible to drag files from the Finder into my SWT application. On Windows and Ubuntu, the following bit of code works:

```
public class DndTest {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.DIALOG_TRIM);
        shell.setText("Drag & drop test");
        shell.setSize(200, 200);
        final FormLayout layout = new FormLayout();
        shell.setLayout(layout);
        final Label lbl = new Label(shell, SWT.NORMAL);
        lbl.setAlignment(SWT.CENTER);
        lbl.setText("Drop files here");
        final FormData layoutData = new FormData();
        layoutData.left = new FormAttachment(50, -100);
        layoutData.top = new FormAttachment(50, -15);
        layoutData.right = new FormAttachment(50, 100);
        layoutData.bottom = new FormAttachment(50, 15);
        lbl.setLayoutData(layoutData);

        final DropTarget dt = new DropTarget(shell,
                DND.DROP_DEFAULT | DND.DROP_MOVE);
        final FileTransfer fileTransfer = FileTransfer.getInstance();
        dt.setTransfer(new Transfer[] { fileTransfer });
        dt.addDropListener(new DropTargetAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void drop(final DropTargetEvent event) {
                System.out.println(event);
                String fileList[] = null;
                final FileTransfer ft = FileTransfer.getInstance();
                if (ft.isSupportedType(event.currentDataType)) {
                    fileList = (String[]) event.data;
                }
                for (final String file : fileList) {
                    System.out.println("- " + file);
                }
            }
        });

        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();

    }

}
```

I get the impression that my application is not registering itself as a drop target on Mac, because hovering files over it does not give me a drop cursor.

I'm using the latest SWT 3.5 (I cannot use 3.6 because for compatibility I need to stick with Carbon & Java 1.5).

Any idea what's wrong here?

**Edit**: I revised the code so that it's a fully enclosed example. It prints the dropped filenames to the console on Windows and Ubuntu, but does nothing on Mac.

Comment: Could you please provide a fully self-contained example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @mklhmnn I've edited the code. All you need to do is specify `import org.eclipse.swt.*`. Also take note that I'm using SWT 3.5.

Comment: I'm using SWT 3.7M4 and the dropped file name is printed. A special drop cursor is not shown, but I'm unsure how it looks like on OSX. I'd suggest to fix/work around your compatibility problem use the latest SWT version.

Comment: Thanks for testing! I had guessed it would be fixed in a later version of SWT, but due to the sheer number of incompatibilities, upgrading really isn't an option for me right now. I was hopeful there might be a JNI/JNA solution.

Comment: This obviously is a limitation in SWT Library. I know sometimes they take time to implement interaction with finder. If it was me, I will try to see if the functionality works in the latest SWT and then will refactor out the necessary code from the latest SWT and use as a custom library. I know its a lot of work, but I do not think that there is any other options.(Other than updating ofcourse)

Comment: Yeah, I'm beginning to think so, too. I'm desperately hoping that there's a simple chunk of (native) code that will interact with drag and drop for Mac, because really everything else works. I almost get the impression that the only limitation is that SWT is not letting the platform know that it can be a drop target. I'll sit the bounty out and hope for the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in SWT ([issue #267381](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=267381) is related, but might not be the actual issue).

As Mike L. pointed out in a comment, it was fixed in SWT 3.7M4.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've got the line

> `dt.addDropListener(new DropTargetAdapter() {`

it could possibly mean the existence of a bug for developing Java SWT applications on Mac OS X (maybe fixed in a later released version possibly?)

do check out the related stackoverflow question phrased another way @ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635170/swt-droptargetlistener-has-empty-event-data-under-mac-os-x)

and it might be exactly your problem already submitted as a bug feature request.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but since you gave some insight, I've awarded you the bounty anyway. Thanks for your help!